# Drag nvd3 line graph using drag behaviour

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I have been working in nvd3 for sometime.

I faced a situation like, I need to drag and align line graph using mouse. [refer here for the pic](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gnamex7kmjog0os/Screenshot%20from%202014-07-14%2014%3A06%3A03.png)

I used d3 functionality

```
   "d3.behaviour.drag().on("drag", move)"
```

and the move function would be

```
  function move(d) {

      d3.select(this)


      .transition()
  //.duration(500)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate("+d3.event.x+")";
        });
  }
```

the problem is this is not working in nvd3 graphs because d3.event.x is not available or may be available in different way. I could not find a way to drag.

But if you put hard code number like

```
return "translate(100)";
```

its working which is in the picture.

Can anyone help me in this situation please to find out d3.event.x functionality in nvd3.

Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. Just get the d3.event.x in a variable and pass that variable to the translate function. It worked.

```
function move(d) {
 var xevent = d3.event.x;

 d3.select(this)
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate("+xevent+")";
    });
 }
```